# How to change direction of .show() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used `.show()` method for my button click event and when i click it's loading from left top corner to right bottom corner. I need to change it to right top corner to left bottom corner. I have tried using every effects in here: https://jqueryui.com/show/ to make this. But I'm unable to do what i need. Here is my code.

```
$("#next").click(function(){
   $(".items li").show(1000);
});
```

I also tried using `.show('effect', { direction: 'right' },'slow');` but it's not what i need. Is there any possible way to change it's direction only using `.show()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible, due to show method only show's the element, displaying it on document as written here: [jQuery .show() doc](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

has two params: duration, complete (callback)

Have you try using [.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: Yes i tried .animate, but it's not working correctly for me.

Comment: I would suggest using CSS here, with .toggleClass("right-bottom") -> .right-bottom { position: absolute; right:0; top:auto; bottom: 0; } and transition

Comment: Thank you @Nate. I'll try it.